# How do I pass parameters into a PHP script through a webpage?

Tags: php, parameters

I am calling a PHP script whenever a webpage loads. However, there is a parameter that the PHP script needs to run (which I normally pass through the command line when I am testing the script).

How can I pass this argument every time the script is run when the page loads?

Comment: Can you post your code, please?

Comment: so you want to run a command line? or a php script?

Comment: Okay, thank you guys. I got the answers below: use $GET and pass it as a parameter value in the url itself.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

Presumably you're passing the arguments in on the command line as follows:

```
php /path/to/wwwpublic/path/to/script.php arg1 arg2
```

... and then accessing them in the script thusly:

```
<?php
// $argv[0] is '/path/to/wwwpublic/path/to/script.php'
$argument1 = $argv[1];
$argument2 = $argv[2];
?>
```

What you need to be doing when passing arguments through HTTP (accessing the script over the web) is using the query string and access them through the $_GET superglobal:

Go to `http://yourdomain.example/path/to/script.php?argument1=arg1&argument2=arg2`

... and access:

```
<?php
$argument1 = $_GET['argument1'];
$argument2 = $_GET['argument2'];
?>
```

If you want the script to run regardless of where you call it from (command line or from the browser) you'll want something like the following:

as pointed out by Cthulhu in the comments, the most direct way to test which environment you're executing in is to use the [PHP_SAPI](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-sapi) constant. I've updated the code accordingly:

```
<?php
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
    $argument1 = $argv[1];
    $argument2 = $argv[2];
}
else {
    $argument1 = $_GET['argument1'];
    $argument2 = $_GET['argument2'];
}
?>
```

Comment: I would use `empty($_GET)`. `$_GET` is a predefined value, so I'm pretty sure it is always set, but empty if there are no GET parameters set. `empty()` returns `false` for empty strings and arrays.

Comment: Without actually checking, I do believe that `$_GET` is in fact not set if the script is called in a command line context.  `empty()` would cause it to look for command line arguments if the script is accessed from the web without a query string, thus throwing more notices.

Comment: $argv[0] isn't actually arg1 in your 1st example, it would be "/path/to/wwwpublic/path/to/script.php". (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that and I keep meaning to come back and update this answer.  Maybe I'll do that now.

Comment: `isset($_GET['argument1'])` and for each argument you need. `$_GET` could be non empty and `$_GET['argument']` be unset.

Comment: I realise i'm late for the party, but the proper way to check is `PHP_SAPI === 'cli'`.

Comment: Not at all, friend! This is a technique I've noticed in passing since I originally wrote this answer up (haven't had need to use it for a while, myself). I kept meaning to look up the specifics and come back to update this answer, now seems as good a time as any to do that.

Comment: @Jason apart of using PHP CLI, is there a way to pass _script arguments_ through a .htaccess directive?

Comment: @emanueledelgrande I'm not entirely sure I follow what you're asking, but I'll try. `.htaccess` is an Apache file - Apache processes incoming requests with the directives in `.htaccess` and then invokes PHP to build the response to the request. So, if you're in the command line, `.htaccess` will be completely ignored. If you're accessing a script through the web, and you want to *add* new querystring arguments after receiving the request, that's typically done with `mod_rewrite`. If that doesn't sufficiently answer your question, I suggest you post a brand new question.

Answer (score 18):

```
$argv[0]; // the script name
$argv[1]; // the first parameter
$argv[2]; // the second parameter
```

If you want to all the script to run regardless of where you call it from (command line or from the browser) you'll want something like the following:

```
<?php
if ($_GET) {
    $argument1 = $_GET['argument1'];
    $argument2 = $_GET['argument2'];
} else {
    $argument1 = $argv[1];
    $argument2 = $argv[2];
}
?>
```

To call from command line `chmod 755 /var/www/webroot/index.php` and use

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/webroot/index.php arg1 arg2
```

To call from the browser, use

```
http://www.mydomain.example/index.php?argument1=arg1&argument2=arg2
```