# how to pass variables to php from command line

Tags: php, linux, command-line

I have a website on my computer on my localhost called testsite. Its on my apache localhost

so i can access a page `http://localhost/testsite/index.php?p=763` from my browser.

index.php includes others php files. The index.php calls back and forth from many other php files in the folder.

so i went into the folder testsite and gave the command 
         `php index.php ?p=763`

but it only shows the result of index.php but not with `?p=763` variable

Also i want to know when i run `php index.php` how to list all the php files it goes through (since there are various functions called from other files).

Answer (score 2):

You could add the following at the beginning of your PHP script:

```
if (isset($argv[1]) && $argv[1][0] == '?') {
    parse_str(substr($argv[1], 1), $_GET);
}
```

It will automatically parse the argument that contains the query parameters and store them in the $_GET variable (thus making it as they came through a browser request).

Still, I wouldn't suggest relying on this approach. You should change your application so that it will handle command line arguments properly.

To see all files that were included you should use the `get_included_files` function at the end of your script:

```
print_r(get_included_files());
```

Comment: what about listing all the php files it goes through

Comment: thats great. it showed all the files. Can i all get all the files list with how many times they are been called and for what function or values

Comment: in my index.php there is no $_GET variable, but it calls to some functions from difference php files which has that $_GET variable. but the number of functions it calls is huge, so how can i  know here to put this code.

Comment: You should put the code at the top of your index.php file. The $_GET variable will be visible inside all of the included files. As for tracing all the calls, this is something that you should implement by yourself - you could probably use the `debug_backtrace` function but it really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

$_GET is only valid for page accessed using your browser. From console, inspect $argv. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9612273/1349128

Comment: what about listing all the php files it goes through

Comment: You could call get_included_files() to get a list of included files.

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to run a script on CLI that is designed for a web request you can cheat by setting the `$_POST` and `$_GET` variables manually from argv

See this post:
http://edmondscommerce.github.io/php/running-php-scripts-on-cli-and-faking-a-web-request.html