# How do I pass parameters to a php script in a bat file

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, localhost

I am trying to add a script that tracks certain statistics and emails me every 24h to windows task scheduler.

The way I do this is with a bat file.

The script runs every minute but only sends an email when I add `email=true` .

In the past I used to run this via xampp with the URL: `http://localhost/path/here/script.php?email=true`

I'm trying to do the same thing from windows task scheduler, but I have no clue on how to add this parameter.

My bat file contains:

```
@ECHO OFF
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f "C:\xampp\htdocs\path\here\script.php?email=true"
```

But this does not seem to do the trick.

Thanks in advance to anyone that is able to help and clarify how this is done properly.

Comment: Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9612273/4726998

Comment: I do not find this to be a duplicate of the above, I'm sorry but I went over that 10 times but it didn't have the means I need to get this to work.

Comment: yeah, I edit my comment it's not a duplicate but your answer is here. :)

Comment: `php /path/to/wwwpublic/path/to/script.php arg1 arg2` does not do anything.

Comment: Sure, because your script is `C:\xampp\htdocs\path\here\script.php` ... Do you want to copy/paste an answer ?

Comment: `@ECHO OFF
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\path\here\script.php email=true" `Does not work is what I meant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CLI parameters work differently. You can run it as

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f "C:\xampp\htdocs\path\here\script.php" -- email=true
```

notice the first `--`, it separates `php.exe` parameters from parameters to your script.

But that is not enough, because parameters are now stored in `$argv` array. So you could check it as `$sendEmail = in_array('email=true', $argv);`.

Alternatively (you need more options), you can use things like [getopt](http://php.net/getopt).

If you need it to be in `$_GET` check out also this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186392/php-passing-get-in-linux-command-prompt).

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, does this mean `script.php` needs to be edited if I use `-- email=true` ?

Comment: Yes, you need edit the `script.php` to correctly retrieve the parameters either the way I've mentioned, or in the linked SO answer.

Comment: Ok, In the script.php there is a line with: `if (isset($_GET['email']) && strtolower($_GET['email']) == "true"){ lots of code }` I do not quite understand the SO answer :(

Comment: Yeah, just replace the current `if (...)` with `if (in_array('email=true', $argv))`.

Comment: Thanks! that seems to have fixed the problem. You made my day :D

Answer (score 0):

for pass parameter from a batch file to a php file you need first add the parameters to the `script.php`

```php
<?php
$argument1 = $argv[1];
$argument2 = $argv[2];
?>
```

now in the batch file its more simple

```
@echo off
path/to/script.php arg1 arg2
```

you can too call args by browser, but the code is modified
here the code (just a example)

```php
<?php
$argument1 = $_GET["arg1"];
$argument2 = $_GET["arg2"];
?>
```

```
@echo off
start http:///localhost/url/to/script.php?arg1=argument%201&arg2=argument%202
rem "%20" is a blank space
```