# how to execute a php file in CL with an argument instead of using the browser.

Tags: php, command-line, terminal

I'm executing a php file via web browser but I used to run it in linux command line by doing:

```
php phpfile.php
```

now I have to use the browser to execute the file because I have to pass an argument like this:

```
localhost/mywebsite/phpfile.php?argument=false
```

Is it possible to still do it in the command line?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9612166/2677083

Comment: It doesn't explain how can I set that argument to false in the command line though. I did php `phpfile.php argument=false` and `php phpfile argument false`. None of them worked.

Comment: The simple answer seems to be, "You can't". Not using `$_GET` anyways. Seems like you will need to create a case that sets the argument when executing the script in a console

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186392/php-passing-get-in-linux-command-prompt

Answer (score 0):

```
php -f somefile.php a=1 b[]=2 b[]=3
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Hope this helps!

Comment: What version of php are you running?

Comment: were you able to figure it out?